# Pod with ClusterIP had a different IP than static IP of ingress

Tags: postgresql, azure, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I'm managing a small Kubernetes cluster on Azure with Postgres. This cluster is accessible through an Nginx controller with a static IP.

The ingress routes to a ClusterIP to a pod which uses a Postgres instance. This Postgres instance has all IPs blocked, with a few exceptions for my own IP and the static IP of the ingress.
This worked well until I pushed an update this morning, where to my amazement I see in the logs an error that the pods IP address differs from the static ingress IP, and it has a permission error because of it.

My question: how is it possible that my pod, with ClusterIP, has a different outer IP address than the ingress static IP I assigned it?
Note that the pod is easily reached, through the Ingress.

Comment: Which version of K8s are you using? Could you add your deployment manifests, and pods logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ingresses` and `Services` handle only incoming pod traffic. Pod outgoing traffic IP depends on Kubernetes networking implementation you use. By default all outgoing connections from pods are source NAT-ed on node level which means pod will have an IP of node which it runs on. So you might want to allow worker node IP addresses in your Postgres.